# Read and modify a vector by multi-threading

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety

I want to create a vector of threads which will doing same job, in my case I just want to take information from a vector of integers.
For example;
I will have got 4 threads and 10 integers.
My threads will get the integers' values. That's all. So I've coded this part but I couldn't solve how can I manage thread vector. How can I read values from this vector by waiting for each thread for the other thread? I would appreciate it if you explain with a sample code snippet.

```
std::condition_variable cond;
std::mutex m_mutex;
std::atomic<int> position_holder {0};
void access_fonksiyon(std::vector<int> myvec){
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locked {m_mutex};
    position_holder++;
    std::cout << "Locked." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Position holder value : "
                << position_holder
                << "thread ID: "
                << std::this_thread::get_id()
                << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    std::vector<int> myvec = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    std::vector<std::thread> thread_vec;
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        thread_vec.push_back(std::thread(access_fonksiyon, std::ref(myvec)));
    }
    for (std::thread &reader : thread_vec){
        reader.join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image: My question is not understood.]

Comment: I have no idea what your question means.  It becomes word salad at one point, with terms that have meaning, but the sentences don't.  Breaking it down into paragraphs, and using more sentences to describe each step, might help.

Comment: Your code already waits for all the threads to complete. After that point, whatever work the threads were doing will have been done and the results will be wherever you coded the threads to put them. If there's nothing you need to do after all the threads are done, then your code is fine as is. If there is, you need to add that code after the joins and before the `return 0;`

Comment: Ok let me give a complete example: let's we have got array which has got 10 integer. My function is summation. So I will add array[i] and array[i+1]. I am creating 2 threads.
std::thread myth1 (func, std::ref(array));
std::thread myth2 (func, std::ref(array));
myth1.join();
myth2.join();
That's all. I've just make 2 calculations. 
I want to do this calculation all of my array with 2 threads. So 2 threads will calculate (50% - 50% of array for each one)

Comment: Yakk sir I've read your approach (consumer-producer) but in my code there will no producer. I just want to consume my vector / queue. So I have got (10 jobs (calculations)) but only will have got maybe 3 threads. But I want to do all jobs with these 3 threads.

Comment: I've added a picture which explaining my purpose. I want to design this for "n number of threads"